# What should I do to join 2 tables based on a condition?

Tags: mysql

I want to join 2 tables: `book_details` and `imdb_index` of those books whose `imdb_index is >=600;`

[image]

Here is what I tried:

```
select *from imdb_index where imdb_index>=600 as x join book_details as y on x.isbn=y.isbn;
```

Comment: At this point 20 minutes in the company of any basic introductory book or tutorial would be beneficial

Comment: Your `WHERE` is in a wrong position. You should do `JOIN .. ON` first then only do `WHERE` .. Which comes to my question, where do you learn how to do `JOIN`? It seems like you stopped after `ON` and figure out the `WHERE` part yourself...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM imdb_index AS x JOIN book_details AS y ON x.isbn = y.isbn 
WHERE x.imdb_index>=600;
```

for more detail about join visit 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Answer (score 0):

The where and join clause are in wrong place

```
    select * 
    from imdb_index x 
    join book_details y on x.isbn=y.isbn
    where y.imdb_index>=600  ;
```

the join clause must precede the where clause

Answer (score 0):

By using the following query you will be able to get the data from your tables  where imdb_index is >=600.

```
   select * 
   from imdb_index as im 
   join book_details as bd
   on im.isbn = bd.isbn 
   where im.imdb_index>=600;
```

You are using `where` condition before the `join`.You should do `Join` first and then only you should use `where`

It's highly recommended to read and watch some tutorials about `joins`.

Following links will help you.

1.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

2.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html